# How can I use a class variable in Python as a default argument for a method?

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to use the class variable `Stock.today` as a default argument for the method `buy_and_hold`, however, my code does not work. The class variable `today`returns today's date as a string. If I type the exact same string (i.e. '2020-6-18') manually as the default argument, the code works. How can I make the code run, using `Stock.today`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf


class Stock:

    year = time.strftime('%Y')
    month = time.strftime('%m').replace("0","")
    day = time.strftime('%d').replace("0","")
    today = Stock.year + '-' + Stock.month + '-' + Stock.day

    def __init__(self,ticker):

        self.ticker = ticker

    # frequency as string # start and end are strings "Y-M-D" # Benchmark as string
    def buy_and_hold(self,frequency,start,end=Stock.today,yfbenchticker='^SPX'):

        sdate_list =[]
        for date in start.split("-"):
            sdate_list.append(int(date))
        sdate = datetime(year=sdate_list[0],month=sdate_list[1],day=sdate_list[2])

        edate_list = []
        for date in end.split("-"):
            edate_list.append(int(date))
        edate = datetime(year=edate_list[0],month=edate_list[1],day=edate_list[2])

        stock = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).history(interval=frequency,start=sdate,end=edate)
        stock.drop(['Dividends','Stock Splits'],axis=1, inplace=True)

        bench = yf.Ticker(yfbenchticker).history(interval=frequency,start=sdate,end=edate)
        bench.drop(['Dividends','Stock Splits'],axis=1, inplace=True)

        # Interpolate missing values
        if stock.isnull().values.any() == True:
            stock['Close'].fillna(value=stock['Close'].mean())

        if bench.isnull().values.any() == True:
            bench['Close'].fillna(value=stock['Close'].mean())

        # Calculate cumulative returns
        stock['Cumulative return'] = stock['Close'] / stock['Close'].iloc[0]
        bench['Cumulative return'] = bench['Close'] / bench['Close'].iloc[0]


        # Plot cumulative returns
        stock['Cumulative return'].plot(color='#00008b',figsize=(16,8))
        plt.plot(bench['Cumulative return'], color='#cd2b00')
        plt.xlabel('Date')
        plt.ylabel('Multiplier')
        plt.legend((self.ticker,yfbenchticker),loc=0,prop={'size':10})

        plt.show()

        return bench


amd = Stock("AMD")
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I get the NameError: name 'Stock' is not defined

Comment: Try adding the variable intialisation in constructor

Comment: You're already in the scope of `Stock` so you should be able to just use `today`.

Answer (score 2):

One way around this is to use a default value of None, and then assign the value you actually want in the function body:

```
def buy_and_hold(self,frequency,start,end=None,yfbenchticker='^SPX'):
    if end is None:
        end = Stock.today
```

However as Mark Ransom commented, you should just be able to use `end=today`.

Comment: Using `end=today` solved my problem. I also had to remove the `Stock`in `Stock.year`,`Stock.month`,`Stock.day`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use self instead of Stock 
And put the initialisation in constructor